# angular-cli ng serve errors

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

angular-cli used to work perfectly, but now I don't know why when creating a new project it doesn't run the server.

I tried reinstalling angular-cli.

I create a new app with `ng new app`.
I navigate into the /app/ path, run `ng serve` and I get:

```
No errors
Error: No errors
    at validate (C:\Users\Gasti\Documents\Prgm\githubsearch\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\schema\validator.js:10:9)
    at Function.ExtractTextPlugin.extract (C:\Users\Gasti\Documents\Prgm\githubsearch\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\index.js:188:3)
    at C:\Users\Gasti\Documents\Prgm\githubsearch\node_modules\angular-cli\models\webpack-build-styles.js:79:83
    at Array.map (native)
    at Object.getWebpackStylesConfig (C:\Users\Gasti\Documents\Prgm\githubsearch\node_modules\angular-cli\models\webpack-build-styles.js:76:43)
    at new NgCliWebpackConfig (C:\Users\Gasti\Documents\Prgm\githubsearch\node_modules\angular-cli\models\webpack-config.js:44:51)
    at Class.run (C:\Users\Gasti\Documents\Prgm\githubsearch\node_modules\angular-cli\tasks\serve-webpack.js:23:22)
    at C:\Users\Gasti\Documents\Prgm\githubsearch\node_modules\angular-cli\commands\serve.run.js:37:22
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [an Angular CLI developer](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4264#issuecomment-275845428):

> This problem arises from a recent update in a external dependency and it's not fixable without a CLI release right now.

He also confirmed that the workaround is to install the dependency at version 2.0.0-rc.0:

```
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.0.0-rc.0 --save-dev
```